# Is n a prime if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n<10^{6}$ and $1<k<n$, $k\nmid n$

Tags: prime-numbers

Can I get hints on how I can explain this?

**Question**
Let $n$ be a positive natural number.
You know the following facts about $n$.
Firstly, $n<10^{6}$.
Moreover, not a single integer $k$ between $1$ and $10^{4}$ divides $n$.
Does it follows that $n$ is prime? Explain your answer.

Comment: What happens if $n $ is not prime? It will have a divisor $k $ greater than $10^4$. Now $n/k $ also divides $n $, but is smaller than $10^4$.

Answer (score 4):

The smallest divisor of $n$ is at most $\sqrt{n}$.  In your case, if $n$ has a non-trivial divisor, then it has a non-trivial divisor of at most $10^{3}=\sqrt{10^{6}}$.

Comment: I'll leave it to you to explain why the smallest non-trivial divisor is at most $\sqrt{n}$.